# Python, Py.test: How can I include local function of another class than that is py.tested?

Tags: python, oop, pytest

I have in my test module:

```
import pytest
from src.model_code.central import AgentBasic

class AgentBasicTestee(AgentBasic):
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def agentBasic():
    return AgentBasicTestee()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('alpha, beta, delta, expected', [
    (2, 1, 1, pytest.approx(1)),
])  
def test_a1(agentBasic, alpha, beta, delta, expected):
    assert(agentBasic.a1(alpha, beta, delta,) == expected)
```

and in my import module

```
from src.model_code.crra_utility import AgentCrra
AgentCOne = AgentCrra

class AgentBasic:
   @staticmethod      
   def a1(alpha, beta, delta):
       k = AgentCOne.k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
       return beta * alpha * (
               alpha - 1) * k ** (alpha - 1)
```

The error message I get is: 
`>       k = AgentCOne.k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
E       TypeError: k_bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'delta'`

Edit:

```
class AgentCrra:
    def k_bar(self, alpha, beta, delta):
        """non-stochastic steady-state for capital"""
        return ((1 / beta - 1 + delta) / alpha) ** (1 / (alpha - 1))
```

So far, self takes one of my parameters s.t. delta stays empty...

Comment: What is `k_bar`?

Comment: `class AgentCrra:
    def k_bar(self, alpha, beta, delta):
        return ((1 / beta - 1 + delta) / alpha) ** (1 / (alpha - 1))`

Comment: is `AgentCOne.k_bar` also a static method? if not, the implicit `self` argument will eat one of your parameters.

Comment: Ah I see! How can i prevent that??

Comment: right, you are calling an instance method as a static method.

Comment: Please update your question with the code for `AgentCrra`. Also please format your code. Python is sensitive to formatting, as are python programmers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Py.Test, How can I prevent self from eating one of my test parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199572/python-py-test-how-can-i-prevent-self-from-eating-one-of-my-test-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `AgentCOne` before calling methods on it. In the simplest case where you can create it with no parameters:

```
AgentCOne().k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
```

Or since `AgentCOne.k_bar` doesn't appear to use any state from the instance (no references to self) you might consider making it static.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did the second one and it worked, but for other test I need to to the first solution. Could you please explain a bit more? Is that all to just create an instance of the class??? Do I not have to write something in the test itself?

Comment: if you are only testing `AgentBasic` then yes, creating an instance of the class in your static methods should be all you need. Why do you need `k_bar` as an instance method?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should make `k_bar` a static method:

```
class AgentCrra:
    @staticmethod
    def k_bar(alpha, beta, delta):
        """non-stochastic steady-state for capital"""
        return ((1 / beta - 1 + delta) / alpha) ** (1 / (alpha - 1))
```

This should allow your unit test to run.

Comment: Hey I did that and it worked! Could you explain how I would need to alter my code if k_bar would not be static? Because for other tests I need to git that way!

Comment: See the answer from @avigil