# How can I prevent self from eating one of my test parameters?

Tags: python, pytest

I have in my test module:

```
import pytest
from src.model_code.central import AgentBasic

class AgentBasicTestee(AgentBasic):
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def agentBasic():
    return AgentBasicTestee()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('alpha, beta, delta, expected', [
    (2, 1, 1, pytest.approx(0.5)),
    (2, 2, 2, pytest.approx(-0.9375 / 0.75)),
])  
def test_b3(agentBasic, AgentCOne,alpha, beta, delta, expected):
    assert(agentBasic.b3(alpha, beta, delta) == expected)
```

and in my import module

```
from src.model_code.crra_utility import AgentCrra
AgentCOne = AgentCrra

class AgentBasic:
    @staticmethod 
    def b3(alpha, beta, delta):
        """define matric element b3"""
        k = AgentCOne.k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
        c = AgentCOne.c_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
        return -c/k
```

The error message I get is:

`>       c = AgentCOne.c_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
E       TypeError: c_bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'delta'`
Note:

```
def c_bar(self, alpha, beta, delta):
    """non-stochastic steady-state for consumption"""
    k = self.k_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
    return k ** alpha  - delta * k
```

So far, self takes one of my parameters s.t. delta stays empty. How can I prevent hat?

Comment: the c_bar definition is in the last code part!

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You should accept the answer though since it seems to have solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to instantiate `AgentCOne` before calling `c_bar` on it because `c_bar` is not a static method (and will take the first argument as `self`).

```
c = AgentCOne.c_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
# should be
c = AgentCOne().c_bar(alpha, beta, delta)
```